# How to auto rollback parent record if child record is not valid in has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Here are 2 models (Rails 4.2) `customer` and `address`. A `customer` `has_one` `address`.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  validates :add_line, :presence => true
end
```

With `autosave` set to true, the `address` is saved along with the `customer`. However if `address` is not valid, then we don't want to save `customer` at all. Our question is that how to set up `has_one` association such that rollback of `customer` happens automatically if the `address` is not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `validates_associated` to validate the address before you save the customer.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
  validates_associated :address
end
```

Comment: can option validate: true do the same?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  If you want to validate that address is valid when you try to save Customer, you should use `validates_associated`

Comment: validate is an option for has_one association.

Comment: That just validates that there's an associated record... it doesn't validate that the associated record is itself valid.  If every customer *must* have an address, thenn you use validate in the `has_one` but if you want to ensure the address record *is itself valid* then you use `validates_associated`.  You may want to use both.